# Group / split string into 2's set

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

This I probably a dumb question but it beats me.

The same thing in Python works perfectly, although in AS3 doesn't.

```
var s:String = "123456";
trace(s.split(/../gm));
```

Expecting this as array: `['12','34','56']`

But instead I get: `[,,]`

I have experimented various regexr patterns but none split into 2-char batches.

Any ideas / solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the [split command](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()), which means the string will be divided into an array of values using the regular expression `..` to match the delimiters. These delimiters are then not included in the output.

I think you want to do something like `s.match(/../g)`. See also [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match()) for more information about `.match`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me, not sure why i was not thinking of actual regx class.